# GoogleUtilities duplication error while archiving IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, analytics

In our project we are using the below pod files for messaging, crashes and analytics . We are able to run the project without issue.

```
pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '4.6.1'
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '6.8.3'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '4.7.0'
```

But while archiving we are getting the below error:

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/Mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IDPal-demuqqbuccbvllafqegxdaobyepx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Staging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework':     
1) Target 'GoogleUtilities-00567490' has create directory command with output '/Users/Mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IDPal-demuqqbuccbvllafqegxdaobyepx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Staging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'     
2) Target 'GoogleUtilities-54e75ca4' has create directory command with output '/Users/Mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IDPal-demuqqbuccbvllafqegxdaobyepx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Staging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'
```

I have tried in legacy mode but I have some more build setting that are affected when we set legacy mode.

Is any other way to fix this?  I have cleared all derived data and clean/archieve I am getting same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workaround for that build system is to explicitly request GoogleUtilities subspecs so that there is no difference in variation subsets.

Details and an example solution at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8206#issuecomment-696754566

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added the pod 'GoogleUtilities' in my pod file, the duplication error gets solved.